# org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: Too many counters: 121 max=120

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I'm running a hadoop job ( from oozie ） that has few counters, and multioutput.

I get error like:
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: Too many counters: 121 max=120

Then I removed all the code that has counters, and also set mout.setCountersEnabled to false.
And also set the max counters to 240 in hadoop config.

Now I still get the same error 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: Too many counters: 241 max=240

How can I solve this problem?
Is there any possibility that any hidden counters exists? 
How can I make clear what counters there before exceeds 240 ? (The process looks like stopped before I can print anything? )

Thanks,
Xinsong

Comment: is this post helpful? 
http://mapredit.blogspot.gr/2012/12/hive-query-error-too-many-counters.html

Comment: I got the reason. It because the multioutput, each multioutput by default has a counter. There are more multioutput after my change, so it get exceed error.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem use the following method:
vi $HADOOP_HOME/conf/mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.counters.limit</name>
    <!--<value>120</value>-->
   <value>20000</value>
    <description>Limit on the number of counters allowed per job. The default value is 200.</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Is there an implication on setting the counter limit too high. I am facing the same issue with value of 2000. Can I increase this to 10000 assuming it to be safe in production.

Comment: For hadoop 2 it called `mapreduce.job.counters.max`

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason. It because the multioutput, each multioutput by default has a counter. There are more multioutput after my change, so it get exceed error.