# Hive query execution failed

Tags: hive

I am executing a hive query and its failing.
I have used the below set parameters.

```
SET hive.execution.engine=tez ;
SET tez.am.resource.memory.mb=4096;
SET hive.tez.container.size=4096;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
SET hive.execution.engine=tez ;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;
```

I am getting the error.

> Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 38,
>   vertexId=vertex_1479183638971_463139_1_22, diagnostics=[Task failed,
>   taskId=task_1479183638971_463139_1_22_000036,
>       diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Container container_1479183638971_463139_01_000556 finished with diagnostics set
>   to [Container failed, exitCode=-104.
>       Container [pid=31713,containerID=container_1479183638971_463139_01_000556] is
>   running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 4.2 GB of 4 GB
>   physical memory used;

So that I have tried with parallel option the below parameters still I am getting some different error.

```
SET hive.execution.engine=tez ;
SET tez.am.resource.memory.mb=4096;
SET hive.tez.container.size=4096;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
SET hive.execution.engine=tez ;
SET hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;
SET tez.am.java.opts=-server -Xmx3276m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseParallelGC;
SET hive.tez.java.opts=-server -Xmx3276m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseParallelGC;
```

I am getting the error.

> Status: Failed
>   Counters limit exceeded: Too many counters: 2001 max=2000 FAILED:
>   Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Counters limit exceeded:
>   Too many counters: 2001 max=2000

Please help me. How to make my query to execute.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you paste the full logs

Comment: We are not mating the log. just whatever the info displayed on the console I have provided

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899050/org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-counters-limitexceededexception-too-many-counters

Comment: Dude thanks for your suggestion>since it's production env I don't have privileges to change it. Any other way would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Dudes any suggestions

Comment: i think you can set using -> SET mapreduce.job.counters.limit=VALUE in hive prompt

Comment: did this work ? @Ram

Comment: No. It's not resolved .Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

SET hive.execution.engine=mr ;
It will work